# TypeError while working with a Python list

Tags: python, list, getline, linecache

In the following code fragment:

```
def func_5_2(datei, num):
    import linecache
    i = 0
    number = num + 1
    l = []
    while True:
        l[i] = linecache.getline(datei, number)
        if (l[i] == ''):
            break
```

Is it possible to fix the problem I get on this line?

```
list[i] = linecache.getline(datei, number)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
File "/home/user/gosection.py", line 27, in func_5_2
  list[i] = linecache.getline(datei, number)
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I see a few problems with your code, but what is your desired outcome?

Comment: Please show how `list` is initialized. Are you sure its a python list?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? E.g. your while loop will never end. The error you are getting comes from `list` which you haven't defined, and since it's a built-in, doesn't raise a `NameError` but a `TypeError`.

Comment: Why is it called func_5_2()? Is this homework?

Comment: Now i inserted list = [] and I've got a new error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: No, it's no homework, it is a part of an research project.

Comment: use `list.append` instead of `list[i]`

Comment: You change completely the topic of your issue! This is a very bad practice and should not be done. For new problems create new topics. Even better: investigate a bit yourself first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this exception because the object `list` is never defined. Initialize `list` before using it.

For example like this:

```
list = []
```

Your code is trying to assign an item to the builtin sequence type [list](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

It is not a good practice to name variables like existing types...
Give the variable another name like `lines`:

```
>>> lines = []
>>> type(lines)
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: okay, one more change, but I don#t understand why I've got now an IndexError: list assignment index out of range .

Comment: use `list.append` instead of `list[i]` to add an item to a list. you cannot set an index of the table that does not exist (yet).

Comment: If my post answers your question flag it as solution in order to reward me. that's how SO works...

Comment: I guess there's no reason to hide the Python builtin named `list` with a local. Why not come up with a better name for the list in question?